# StyledText cannot change style with setStyleRanges()

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

The StyledText widget shows a piece of Java code, and it uses a JavaLineStyler for syntax highlighting. However, I would like to show some tokens as selected using

```
codeViewer.setStyleRanges(sranges); //sranges is an array of StyleRange
```

But looks like the second round style change is prevented by the following code snippet in the StyledText widget source.

```
public void setStyleRanges(StyleRange[] ranges) {
checkWidget();
if (isListening(ST.LineGetStyle)) return;
if (ranges == null) SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT);
setStyleRanges(0, 0, null, ranges, true);
```

}

Not sure how to keep the syntax highlighting alive and then show some tokens selected.

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why the downvotes?

Comment: @owlstead, are you referring to syntax highlighting in the StyledText? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `LineStyleListener` and `setStyleRanges` at the same time, you must use all one or the other.

You could look at the JFace `TextViewer`, `SourceViewer` and `TextPresentation` classes which provide ways to set styles on `StyledText`, these use `setStyleRanges`.